# Find image of a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to 2^\mathbb{N}$, $(0\in \mathbb{N})$; $f(n) = \{ k\in \mathbb{N} :2^k | n\}$.

Tags: functions

I have such function $f: \mathbb{N} \to 2^\mathbb{N}$, $(0\in \mathbb{N})$;  $f(n) = \{ k\in \mathbb{N} :2^k | n\}$. Find image of $f(P)$ and $f^{-1}(P)$, where $P$ is a set of prime numbers.

I actually dont understand what $2^\mathbb{N}$ is, is it a set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, and the function $f$ gives all the non-negative integers less than $K$, where $K$ is the power of $2$ in the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: Hint for $f(P)$: if $p\in P$, then what is $f(p)$?

Comment: In general, if $A,B$ are sets, then $A^B$ denotes the set of functions from $B\to A$.  If $A$ is a set with $2$ elements, informally written as "$A=2$", then this is the same as the set of subsets of $B$ since specifying a subset is the same as specifying a function to $\{0,1\}$ (if $S\subset B$, then $F_S(b)=1$ if and only if $b\in S$).  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Set_theory) for a reference to the notation.

Comment: Note that $f(2) = \{0,1 \}$ and for any odd prime $p$ we have $f(p) = \{0\}.$ So $$f(P) = \bigcup\limits_{p \in P} f(p) = \{0,1\}.$$

Comment: $f(P)$ should be a set of *subsets* of $\Bbb N.$  @AnilBagchi.

Answer (score 0):

$2^\Bbb N=\mathscr P(\Bbb N)$ is the *power set*, or the set of all subsets of $\Bbb N .$  Intuitively,  for each natural number,  it can either be in the subset, or not. Thus a subset identifies naturally with a function from $\Bbb N$ to a two element set.

If $P$ is a set of more than one primes with $2\in P,$ then $f(P)=\{\{0\},\{0,1\}\}$, and $f^{-1}(P)=\emptyset.$

Comment: Are you sure, because I thought that this function`s output should be a set of k,  in a power of which 2^k devides every number in a set of prime numbers.

Comment: I thought it was just a set of {1,0}

Comment: @Alex I agree with you. I mean $\{0,1\}$ if $2 \in P$; otherwise, just $\{0\}$.

Comment: @amrsa Thanks) Yeah, 2 belongs to P. And the  $f^{-1} $would be just all rationals??

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already concluded that
$$
f(P)=
\begin{cases}
\{0,1\} & \text{if }2 \in P,\\
\{0\} & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Now,
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(P)
&= \{n \in \mathbb N : f(n) \in P\}\\
&= \left\{n \in \mathbb N : \left\{k \in \mathbb N : 2^k|n\right\} \in P\right\}.
\end{align}

Now, if $2^p|n$, then certainly $2^1=2|n$ (and, of course, $2^0=1|n$), but $0$ and $1$ are not primes.
So there is no $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $2^p|n$ but $2{\nmid}n$, i.e., for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if
$\left\{k \in \mathbb N : 2^k|n\right\}$ includes some prime $p$, it must include all naturals $m\leq p$, and so $f^{-1}(P)=\varnothing$.